# How to run a open source nodejs code

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am very very new to nodejs. I have this application that I have downloaded from github. It is using Gulp for building. I tried that it worked and I now have the exe file. What I really not able to find out is how can I run the application so that I can do the some customization in the app. I really need do few customizations. I dont think its very productive to build the app every time you do a  slight changes in the javascript or css. I am trying https://github.com/butterproject/butter-desktop. How can I run this in browser and be able to do minor changes in javascript that reflect in the browser right away ?

Comment: "I don't think its very productive to rebuild the app to test minor changes" that's your opinion and you have a right to it, but you are swimming upstream... except in the case of CSS, that's pretty easy to live edit in devtools. Just use gulp watch and livereload to automatically rebuild and refresh when you make changes to the source.

Comment: So that means building an exe is needed every single time ? I thought we can make server on nodejs and then server file on to it and see them in browser and then do the changes right away. I tried serving src/bootstrap.js but no go. So I wanted to know may be there is some standard way to serve node apps so that they are available on browser and then you can just do the changes right away ?

Comment: You seem to be confused here about the difference between the *client* and the *server*. You should never need to restart the server unless you change the code *in the actual server file*. You should be able to rebuild the project without restarting the server.